# $_GET dynamic method call malfunctioning as index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteBase /action
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ action.php?fid=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ action.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ action.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

So this is placed in folder `/action`

Now the file `http://domain/action/action.php?fid=` can be called as `http://domain/action/{fid}` where `fid` is function name which is called like below:

```
<?php 
class Actions{

    function call($func){
        if(method_exists($this, $func) == true){
            $this->$func();
        } else {
            http_response_code(403);
            echo "403 Forbidden";
        }
    }

    private function deleteFile(){
        if(isset($_POST['auth'])){
            if(!cookie_login($_POST['auth'])){
                echo '403';
            } else {
                if(isset($_POST['token'])){
                    if(delete_file($_POST['token'])){
                        echo '200';
                    } else {
                        echo '500';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '404';
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo '404';
        }
    }
}

print_r($_GET);
$action = new Actions();
$action->call($_GET['fid']);
```

Now I am calling `deleteFile()` method like `http://domain/action/deleteFile` which has `$_GET['fid']` equals `deleteFile` as per the code.

But, that is not happening.

**Case 1 Output:**

*Method: `POST`*

*URL: `http://domain/action/deleteFile`*

```
Array
(
    [fid] => index.php
)
403 Forbidden
```

**Case 2 Output:**

*Method: `GET`*

*URL: `http://domain/action/deleteFile`*

```
Array
(
    [fid] => deleteFile
)
404
```

**Description:** There is no POST parameters here, that why it is echoing 404, but method executing.

**Try 1:** Change `$_GET` and `$_POST` into `$_REQUEST`

Results doesn't change.

Now look at the **Case 1 Output**.

`fid` should be `deleteFile` but it is `index.php`. If I comment out the `$this->$func();` which is inside the `Action->call($func)` method, here is the output.

*Method: `POST` or `GET`*

*URL: `http://domain/action/deleteFile`*

```
Array
(
    [fid] => deleteFile
)
```

which shows, only when `$this->$func();` this line is there in `Action->call($func)`, it is not malfunctioning. Where the `index.php` comes from? Weird!!

I really have no idea about this issue. Please help.

Comment: What does `cookie_login` look like? Can you post the code of that function?

Comment: I think I already got the issue.. The trouble is with cookie_login.. I was trying without setting the cookie. Please post it as the answer and I will mark it as working..!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your `cookie_login` function is probably messing with the `$_REQUEST['fid']` variable. All the other code seems to be working as expected when I spun it up in a local dev instance.

Comment: Thanks.. I forgot to set the cookie, which caused the entire mess!!